# Como usar código do github live, para desenvolvimento, testes e demos?

Tags: github

Como posso usar código do GitHub em tempo real numa demo ou em desenvolvimento?
Quando tento usar código no jsFiddle ou jsBin recebo o erro:

> Refused to execute script from `https://raw.github.com/utilizador/repositorio/ficheiro.js` because its MIME type ('text/plain') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Exemplo: [**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/W9eqL/) (ver erro na consola)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A solução é usar um serviço do Github que disponibiliza os ficheiros com o cabeçalho `content type` correcto.

Asim o url disponibilizado é quase o mesmo, só precisa de remover o `.` (ponto)

**Antes**

```
https://raw.github.com/utilizador/repositorio/ficheiro.js
           ^
```

**Depois**

```
https://rawgithub.com/utilizador/repositorio/ficheiro.js
// ou mais recente:
https://rawgit.com/utilizador/repositorio/ficheiro.js
```

[**Mais info**](https://rawgithub.com/) <sup>(em Inglês)</sup>

---

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5UrTL/)